# How to fix 'TypeError: youTubeIframeAPIReady is not a function' in Angular Elements for multiple players on a page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, youtube-iframe-api

I have several custom angular elements on my index.html page called `<my-video>` that each loads a video player via the YouTube Iframe API. I have a single callback defined for the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady callback that is fired on the window object when the API script has loaded. The callback sets up the video player. In order to setup multiple players, I am calling the window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] callback manually inside of the callback (it calls itself). The result: each player loads fine and functions as expected. After the final player is created, I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: youTubeIframeAPIReady is not a function". For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to resolve the console TypeError. Please help.

This is a video component in a component library using Angular custom elements instead of a full application.

Index.html

```html
<my-video some-property="some value"></my-video>
<my-video some-property="some value"></my-video>
```

Video.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {
  videoYoutubeId = 'WWXfdIK1WxA';
  private player: any;
  private YT: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadYoutubeScript();
    this.createVideoPlayer();
  }

  loadYoutubeScript() {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

  createVideoPlayer() {
    const youTubeIframeAPIReady = window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'];

    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = () => {

      this.YT = window['YT'];
      const iframeId = this.videoYoutubeId.toLowerCase();
      this.player = new window['YT'].Player(iframeId, {
        events: {
          'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this)
        }
      });

      youTubeIframeAPIReady(); // <==== Uncaught TypeError: youTubeIframeAPIReady is not a function
    };
  }

}
```

Video.component.html

```html
<iframe
   [id]="videoYoutubeId | lowercase"
   width="640"
   height="360"
   style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
   frameborder="0"
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WWXfdIK1WxA?controls=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&html5=1&fs=0">
</iframe>
```

I expect to be able to load several video elements into my index page and for each video to have it's own player that I can then retrieve info for or control via the typescript. I need a way to eliminate the error: "Uncaught TypeError: youTubeIframeAPIReady is not a function" after the last player is created.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call another method from an anonymous function is by using an arrow function to trigger the method like:

> let readyFuction = () => this.youTubeIframeAPIReady();